# PHP ISO 8601 format and SQL Server - Timezone

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, zend-framework, datetime, pdo

When trying to insert data programatically using PHP, via the function

```
date('c')
```

It returns a date in the following format...

```
2011-12-20T19:01:03+11:00
```

But this is not suitable when inserting into a SQL Server database. It will return with the error...

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Now of course there are many ways to get around this problem. One could easily go through and change the format when inserting the data and specify yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (not accurate). However, I would rather prefer to use the date('c') format and rely on that call to take care of my issue.

I am connecting to the database using PDO and Zend_DB.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have any problem using date('c') with MySQL. Which database are you using?

Comment: It's a SQL Server 2008 database actually. On that note, MySQL works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is type of field that you use for date storage? It won't work for datetime.

Quick test:

```
-- shows error
CREATE TABLE #tmp1 (
    c1 varchar(30),
    dto1 datetimeoffset,
    dt1 datetime
)
GO

INSERT INTO #tmp1 (
    c1,
    dto1,
    dt1
) VALUES (
    '2011-12-20T19:01:03+11:00',
    '2011-12-20T19:01:03+11:00',
    '2011-12-20T19:01:03+11:00'
)
GO

SELECT * FROM #tmp1

DROP TABLE #tmp1
GO

-- works - datetime2
CREATE TABLE #tmp2 (
    c1 varchar(30),
    dto1 datetimeoffset,
    dt2 datetime2
)
GO

INSERT INTO #tmp2 (
    c1,
    dto1,
    dt2
) VALUES (
    '2011-12-20T19:01:03+11:00',
    '2011-12-20T19:01:03+11:00',
    '2011-12-20T19:01:03+11:00'
)
GO

SELECT * FROM #tmp2

DROP TABLE #tmp2
GO
```

Comment: Thank you BartekR, this worked for me. I had no idea about the datetime2 datatype until now.